# Class [+] was not found while converting from class names to classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, eclipselink

I have a map in the field, which assumes as the key the entity inheriting after MovieInfo and the same value.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(
        name="contributions_elements_to_update",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "contribution_id")
)
@MapKeyColumn(name="new_element")
@Column(name = "old_element")
private Map<? extends MovieInfo, ? extends MovieInfo> elementsToUpdate;
```

When compiling, the compiler sends out a mistake

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException: 
Exception Description: Class: [+] was not found while converting from class names to classes.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: +
```

https://pastebin.com/QUpGa2PV

Comment: Looks like it tried to load a class with name "+" and of course, failed there. I believe the problem is another piece of code.

Comment: But like in another code. I have created this entity and a map and it cannot even be compiled.

Comment: Stacktrace is like from spring context starting - so it was compiled